# The url is not constructed as it should be according to the route defined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

i'm using telerik grid for mvc. I am using ajax binding, following is the code

```
 colums.Bound(o => o.SomeNumber)
.Groupable(false)
.ClientTemplate(Html.ActionLink("<#=SomeNumber#>", "ActionResult", "ControllerName", new { docid = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["docid"], id = "<#=RequisitionID#>" }).ToString())
.Title("Some No.")
.Width(100);
```

i have a route defined as

```
routes.MapRoute(
              "strict",
              "{controller}.mvc/{docid}/{action}/{id}",
              new {docid = "",action = "Index", id = ""},
              new { docid = @"\d+"}

            );
```

and i expect the url to be like

```
<a href='ControllerName.mvc/docid/ActionResult/id'>SomeNumer</a>
```

where as the url that is contructed is like

```
<a id="32" href="/ControllerName.mvc/docid/ActionResult?Length=3" docid="160">SomeNumber</a>
```

i have failed to understand why its not being constructed according to the route defined, i have defined the route above the default route if that matters.

Please help me find out where i went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using the [wrong overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx) of ActionLink, and a the route values are interpreted as HTML attributes.

Try [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx) istead (note the `null` as the last parameter)

```
Html.ActionLink(
    "<#=SomeNumber#>", //Link text
    "ActionResult", // Action name
    "ControllerName", //Controller name
    new { docid = "...", id = "..." }, //route values
    null //html attributes
)
```

Comment: i wish i could upvote you a 100 times, tnx that fixed it, i have fallen to this null trap a million times during the course of my current prj yet i can't see it every time...tnx again